'Modus': takes an infinitive or a genitive gerund?
I asked ChatGPT (bold face not in original):

Does this have good Latinitas?
Quam beātus modus diem incipiendī!

It replied:

The phrase "Quam beātus modus diem incipiendī!" attempts to convey something like "What a blessed way of starting the day!" However, it could use some adjustments for better Latin expression.
Here’s a refined version:
"Quam beātus modus diem incipere!"

I queried it further and it insisted that the infinitive is conventional classical style and the genitive gerund is not. I brought up modus operandi and modus vivendi and it said that these are idiomatic expressions that don't follow the normal pattern. Then I asked it for some classically attested examples of modus with an infinitive complement. It said that there are very few, and concluded by saying "a more classically faithful phrase would be: Quam beātus modus diem incipiendī!"
So which is it? Does modus for "a way to do something" or "a way of doing something" take an infinitive or a genitive gerund (or either, as in English)?

O quam beātus modus diem incipiendī est quaestiōnem in latin.stackexchange.com prōpōnere!

Why all the downvotes? Because I asked ChatGPT?

I think it's because you seem to have used it as your only source. If you get an inspiration from a chat with an intelligence, whether artificial or natural, you should check the idea against more reputable sources. Given how unreliable AI tools are for factual correctness, I think this question looks essentially equivalent to "does this random string of letters mean anything in Latin?".

@JoonasIlmavirta Oh well. I thought folks might have some fun outdoing ChatGPT. Maybe I shouldn't have omitted the really nonsensical things it said. ;) BTW, claude.ai also objected to the Latinity of my sentence, but not because of the gerund. It suggested wholly different approaches to render the same thought—a little closer to the kind of answer one usually gets here.

Involving ChatGPT is not an issue in itself. It's just that you should check a dictionary or grammar or corpus or whatever is relevant. It generally works well if you try to answer your own question and tell how that attempt left you thinking. When users on any SE site smell lack of effort to self-solve, downvotes often head your way. I think this was an instance of just that.

An excellent question, and it illustrates just how bad machine translation is for Latin. Thanks for the laughs.

L&S cite Statius ("nam quis erit saevire modus?") and Vergil ("nec modus inserere atque oculos imponere simplex") for modus + infinitive. They mark this usage as poetic in both cases, and the normal construction certainly uses a genitive; there are more examples listed with a gerund in the genitive than with an infinitive.
